# VSCode Run Button Open External Terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have two questions for you;

Is there any way to just build and run c code internal terminal when I press to button given figure below. Just there is build and debug options.

[image: Figure 1]

Is there any way to open debug in internal terminal not new pop-up window like figure below.

[image: Figure 2]

Here is my task and json files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you use "run" it will not use terminal but runs like it is ".exe". If you want terminal, then you need to compile and run code in terminal by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle this problem with code runner extension. First I added extension then from settings enabled run code in terminal.

[image]