# VS Code C++ ran code twice in both external and integrated terminals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am testing a simple cpp (below) in VSCode, but when click "Run Code", the program ran twice. First it opens an external terminal. When complete, the code also runs in the integrated terminal. How can I run it just once?

VSCode extensions enabled:

- C/C++ Extension Pack (v1.3.0 by Microsoft)
- CMake (v0.0.17 by twxs)
- Code Runner (v0.12.0 by Jun Han)

C++ compiler:

- Mingw-w64

I have tried disabling/enabling Code Runner, and used "RunInTerminal" True/False as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598362/vscode-run-button-open-external-terminal). But, VSCode still runs twice.

```
#include <iostream>

int sum_of_two_digits(int first_digit, int second_digit) {
    return first_digit + second_digit;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << sum_of_two_digits(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your antivirus is the problem? Do you have an AV with a sandbox mode like Avast?

Comment: I do! Will try again with that disabled. Curious. How could that cause the issue?

Comment: I don't think I have the sandbox mode actually. But when I turned off Antivirus briefly it no longer runs external terminal.

Comment: ***How could that cause the issue?*** A sandbox mode causes your program to be executed 2 times. Once in the sandbox where the AV prevents it from causing harm and verifies the behavior in the sandbox and then if it does not believe your application is a virus it runs it a second time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! FYI If you add this to answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for this behavior could be your antivirus. Some AV like Avast have a sandbox mode where your unknown executable (not known by its database of signatures) is run once first in the sandbox and then if your program does not appear to be a virus the AV will run it a second time normally.